# How do I implement jquery.sound.js?

Tags: jquery, audio

I want a button to make a blip sound when moused over.

I want to use jquery.sound.js

I found this above plugin and I like jquery. But I can find NO documentation on how to employ it.

I understand from another half-assed answer to this same question that sound.js configures itself according to the file url you supply...(?)

But where does one write in the url?

What kind of element do I make for it? A span? A division? What must its id be?

Also, if the embed element is injected dynamically, how is one supposed to see it to write in the URL?

Like 95% of "help" I search for, the answer I found was totally useless for a person not used to using jquery plugins.

People: If you enjoy others, that's fantastic. Just *please* do a thorough job of it or it just frustrates and wastes people's time as they have to start over with yet another search... Sometimes it takes me six different websites before I get an understandable answer that includes an example of how to write the HTML, javascript or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say you are novice to `javascript` and `jQuery`? Here is a simple steps to play a sound...

Include `jQuery.js` and `jquery.sound.js`.

Here is one way to play the sound from a `url`

```
$.sound.play(url)
```

Other options from documention

```
/**
 * API Documentation
 * 
 * // play a sound from the url
 * $.sound.play(url)
 * 
 * // play a sound from the url, on a track, stopping any sound already running on that track
 * $.sound.play(url, {
 *   track: "track1"
 * });
 * 
 * // increase the timeout to four seconds before removing the sound object from the dom for longer sounds
 * $.sound.play(url, {
 *   timeout: 4000
 * });
 * 
 * // stop a sound by removing the element returned by play
 * var sound = $.sound.play(url);
 * sound.remove();
 * 
 * // disable playing sounds
 * $.sound.enabled = false;
 * 
 * // enable playing sounds
 * $.sound.enabled = true
 */
```

Here is the source code to understand

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/source/browse/trunk/plugins/sound/jquery.sound.js?r=5750

Comment: Thank you, Teja, but you gave me only a hint of an answer... just as I was talking about. It's totally out of context and doesn't tell me where to put the command. Do I write that wrapped in <script></script> and put it in the head? If so, how do I call it onmouseover or on mouseenter? In other words, I still have no idea what to do with it when writing my page. It's supposed to trigger a short chirp once whenever any button is rolled over.

Comment: Yes, you have to add **any** javascript inside the `script` tag. also you have to add this code in the `document ready` function of `jQuery` just to make sure your DOM is ready when your code is about to execute.